# Trigger BrowserSync reload from url request?

Tags: javascript, browser-sync

Is there any way to trigger a full BrowserSync refresh by requesting a url?

The case for this would be some proxied web app with a database component. When something in the database was changed, an update hook could ping a url to trigger a BrowserSync reload.

It seems like this should be possible by requesting some url on `localhost:3001`, but I haven't found this kind of thing mentioned in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible and it's fantastic.

[BrowserSync 2.6.0](https://github.com/BrowserSync/browser-sync/releases/tag/2.6.0) added support for HTTP endpoints which are exactly what I was looking for: An HTTP request can trigger a reload on all connected devices. Requests can originate locally or externally. The address for a basic reload looks like this:

> `http://localhost:3000/__browser_sync__?method=reload`

Endpoints can also accept arguments to target specific files.

[BrowserSync HTTP Protocol docs](http://www.browsersync.io/docs/http-protocol/)